# Get the last value from subscribe

Tags: angular, angular6, ngrx, rxjs6

I have the function `getCurrentStatus()` that returns a boolean value, when I subscribe to this method it always return null then true, when I try to get the last value (true) using the function last() of rxjs, it doesn't work, it always executes treatment 2, which returns null from the beginning.

```
import { last } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.getCurrentStatus().pipe(last()).subscribe(status => {
  console.log(status);
  if (status) {
    // treatment 1 
  } else {
   // treatment 2
  }
});

  private status$: Subscription;

  getCurrentStatus(): Observable<Boolean> {
    if (!this.status) {
      this.status$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromUserSelector.getAuthStatus)).subscribe((status: Boolean) => {
        this.status = status;
      });
    }
    return of(this.status);
  }
```

Comment: Because your return statement is outside the subscribe function and you are performing an async operation in getting the data from the store

Comment: There are a couple of things that look weird with this code. What type is `this.status$`? The convention is to have a dollar sign at the end of Observables, but this is a Subscription. Also, what is `select`? Is it an alias for `map`? And as @Suryan said, you're not using observables and subscriptions right. You're thinking synchronously

Comment: @ShamPooSham `this.status$` is the subscription actually what he/she thinks of this as `Observable` and by the select is used as he/she is using ngrx/store to maintain the state of application